# Highslide - Draggable header with Close button

Tags: highslide

***[Edit: Although I did get an answer, it doesn't work when there are multiple html expanders in the same page.  Please see my [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579811/highslide-entire-header-draggable-with-multiple-expanders).]***

This should sooo be easy to do!  I'm using htmlExpand.

All I want from Highslide is a draggable header, as shown here, with an X in it to the right to close. I'm surprised this isn't built-in and ready-to-go in highslide, but alas it seems to only "almost" work.

In the graphic, the grey/blue background of the heading text represents the draggable area.  (I'm using a translucent .png as the background of .highslide-heading.  The X graphic is actually behind it.)

I would like the draggable area to extend almost all the way to the right, stopping just a few pixels short of the X, making almost the whole header draggable like a window.

As-shown, I have the width of highslide-heading at 100% and the X isn't clickable because it's "behind" the draggable space.  If I change the width of .highslide-heading to 90%, it works, but the grey area is shorter and it looks weird.

Of course, I could experiment with percentages, but I have several pop-up items on the same page, and they vary in size so no particular percentage will be right for all.  (P.S. Results vary by browser anyway.)

Please bear in mind I wish to continue to use htmlExpand as opposed to other approaches so I can be flexible with my content that pops up.  (I know the example shown here could easily use other approaches to expand in Highslide, since it's only a picture and a caption.)

THE SOLUTION I'M SEEKING: Somehow, I believe I need the close button to be "on top" of the draggable space.  I believe the CSS property I need is z-index, but I have no idea where or how to insert it.  It seems to have no effect in the .CSS file no matter where I put it.

Help would be greatly appreciated.  I *DO* give check right answers and upvote people.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `hs.registerOverlay` suggested by EarlyOut, or you can use the premade `wrapperClassName: 'draggable-header'` (or `hs.wrapperClassName = 'draggable-header';` if you prefer to use it as a global setting), which can do everything you ask for with a few changes in the CSS.

I assume you already are using `wrapperClassName: 'draggable-header'`, but you need to add the background color for the header to the correct CSS selector to achieve what you want, and you also need to use a transparent X (close) graphic file and a few lines of additional CSS. 
Please see this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/roadrash/mXmLN/

Comment: Hi RoadRash.  If you're who I think you are it's good to hear from you.

Comment: I went to that JsFiddle and was blown away because it looks exactly like what I'm doing already, except yours works and mine doesn't.  So, clearly the answer lies in comparing what you provided to what I've done.  Haven't found it yet but I will and obviously it will work, so you get the coveted green checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you pointed in the right direction. Take a look at RoadRash's coding on this demo page:

http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/iframe-closebutton-redirect.html

But since you want a regular "close" on the X, rather than a redirect, change the "html" attribute on the overlay to the standard:

```
html: '<div class="closebutton" onclick="return hs.close(this)" title="Close"></div>',
```